# Energy method - wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have a 2D wave equation $u_{tt} =c^2u_{xx}$ subject to the boundary conditions $$a_0u(0, t)-b_0u_x (0, t) = 0$$ $$a_1u(1, t)+b_1u_x (1, t) = 0$$ for constants $a_0, b_0, a_1, b_1$ with $b_0\neq0$ and $b_1\neq 0$.

1. Calculate the derivative $E'(t)$ of the energy.
2. How should $E(t)$ be modified in order to remain constant in time with these new boundary conditions?
3. What constraints should be imposed on $a_0, b_0, a_1, b_1$ to ensure the modified energy is a nonnegative function of $u$?

---

By differentiating with respect to $t$, we find, $$\frac{dE}{dt}=2\int_0^1((u_tu_{tt}+c^2u_xu_{xt})dx.$$ Next integrating the second term on the right side by parts gives 
\begin{align*}
\frac{dE}{dt} &=2\int_0^1 u_t(u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx})dx+c^2u_xu_t\Big|_0^1 \\
\end{align*}
Given our PDE and boundary conditions,
\begin{align*}
a_0u(0,t)-b_0u_x(0,t)=0 \implies u_x(0,t)=\frac{a_0}{b_0}u(0,t) \\
a_1u(1,t)+b_1u_x(1,t)=0 \implies u_x(1,t)=-\frac{a_1}{b_1}u(1,t)
\end{align*}
we find,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dE}{dt} &= 2\int_0^1 u_t(0)dx-c^2\Big[\frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_0}{b_0}\Big]uu_t\Big|_0^1 \\
&= -c^2\Big[\frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_0}{b_0}\Big]uu_t\Big|_0^1.
\end{align*}

If we define $c^2=\frac{a_1}{b_1}-\frac{a_0}{b_0}$, we ensure that $E'(t)=0$ and $E(t)$ remain constant in time.

And letting $\frac{a_1}{b_1}\ge\frac{a_0}{b_0}$, we ensure $E$ is non-negative: $$E(t)=\int_0^1 (u_t)^2+\big(\frac{a_1}{b_1}-\frac{a_0}{b_0}\big)(u_x)^2dx.$$